# What is "starting from sshd"?

Tags: bash, git, git-bash

My `/etc/bash.bashrc` contains this code by default (Git for Windows)

```
# If started from sshd, make sure profile is sourced
if [[ -n "$SSH_CONNECTION" ]] && [[ "$PATH" != *:/usr/bin* ]]; then
  . /etc/profile
fi
```

I know it is documented, but I still don't understand what it means. I set an `echo "here"` inside of the if to see if it ever runs, but I can't make it. What exactly does this mean, and what even is an sshd? Or did I accidentally just type "d" on my keyboard and its a typo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.ssh.com/ssh/sshd/

> `sshd` is the OpenSSH server process. It listens to incoming connections using the SSH protocol and acts as the server for the protocol. It handles user authentication, encryption, terminal connections, file transfers, and tunneling.

That code checks if the `$SSH_CONNECTION` environment variable is set to see if the shell was started by sshd. If so, and `$PATH` does not contain `/usr/bin`, then it executes the commands in `/etc/profile` in the current shell context.

Comment: Minor addition: `echo "here"` never works because `$PATH` always contains `/usr/bin`; perhaps because `/bin:/usr/bin` is the default `$PATH`.